# Rails ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in my model:

```
attr_accessor :expiry_date
validates_presence_of :expiry_date, :on        => :create, :message => "can't be blank"
```

and the following in my view:

```
<%= date_select :account, :expiry_date, :discard_day => true, :start_year => Time.now.year, :end_year => Time.now.year + 15, :order => [:month, :year]  %>
```

However, when I submit my form I get:

```
ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors in SignupController#create

/Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p383/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:3073:in `execute_callstack_for_multiparameter_attributes'
/Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p383/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:3028:in `assign_multiparameter_attributes'
/Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p383/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2750:in `attributes='
/Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p383/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2438:in `initialize'
```

Any ideas as to what the problem might be?  I've looked at [#93277](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93277/what-does-activerecordmultiparameterassignmenterrors-mean) with no joy, so am kinda stuck.

Adding day to the select does NOT resolve the issue.

Ultimately what I am trying to acheive is a property of the model that is not saved to the database, but is validated.  This already appears to work for some other simple string fields in the same model, just not the :expiry_date

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this SO will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541786/rails-activerecordmultiparameterassignmenterrors

Comment: Did you try removing attr_accessor?

Comment: @Johnathan - you've linked to my own question.  It might help, but I doubt it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use attr_accessor it means you're not storing that field in the DB.

The issue remains in the fact that you cannot use a non-persistent model attribute (ie: not actually stored into the DB via the model) with helpers.

That's why Rails 3 has got ActiveModel: to use any object, include some ActiveModel behavior (via module inclusion), and use it with ActionPack's helpers (if I understood it all well :)).

Try replacing `attr_accessor` by `attr_accessible` or even drop that line if you want to protect that field from mass-assignment.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L1764, Rails will ask the class what's the type for that column. Since that attribute is not a column, we'll get nil, and nil has no method klass. So, I just patched `column_for_attribute`. I put this in my class (my attribute was `birth_date`):

```
def column_for_attribute_with_birth_date(name)
  if name == 'birth_date'
    return Object.new.tap do |o|
      def o.klass
        Date
      end
    end
  end
  column_for_attribute_without_birth_date(name)
end
alias_method_chain :column_for_attribute, :birth_date
```

Comment: a shorter and somewhat cleaner way to do this is the following (in the context of the class): `columns_hash["birth_date"] = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new("birth_date", nil, "date")`

Comment: Much better, indeed. Thank you!