# Type casting values during an attr_accessor

Tags: ruby

I am a newbie to Ruby and am learning it using "Programming Ruby 1.9" (PickAxe). In the book, I see a program which I modified thus:

```
 1 #!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
 2 
 3 class BookInStock
 4         attr_reader :isbn
 5         attr_accessor :price
 6         def initialize(isbn, price)
 7                 @isbn = isbn
 8                 @price = Float(price)
 9         end
10 #       def price=(price)
11 #               @price = Float(price)
12 #       end
13 end
14 
15 b1 = BookInStock.new("isbn1", 3)
16 p b1
17 b2 = BookInStock.new("isbn2", 3.14)
18 p b2
19 b3 = BookInStock.new("isbn3", "5.67")
20 p b3
21 b3.price = "10.32"
22 p b3
```

Line number 8 ensures that the right value is assigned to `b3.price`.

But how do I handle cases like line number 21 without using a method like in line 10-12?

Is there some way in which I can modify the `attr_accessor` for this? Or am I asking for too much :D

I could not find any such references online.

Comment: You should never store prices in `Float`s. `0.30 + 0.30 + 0.30` yields `0.8999999999999999`.

Comment: If you need to do financial computations then use [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) instead of `Float`

Comment: Thanks. Read about that in some other reference. Just that this was a trivial example to start with. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr_accessor :sym` is a method of a Class that defines simple getter and setter methods.

You can define your own `casting_attr_accessor`:

```
class Class

 def casting_attr_accessor(accessor, type)

     define_method(accessor) do  
       instance_variable_get("@#{accessor}")
     end        

     define_method("#{accessor}=") do |val| 
       instance_variable_set("@#{accessor}", Kernel.send(type.to_s, val))
     end
 end
end
```

And then in your class use it like

```
casting_attr_accessor :price, Float
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this without writing your own setter method. What `attr_accessor :method` does internally is just generate you the simplest possible setter method:

```
def method=(val)
    @method = val
end
```

You need to write more advanced setter method (in your case setter will contain string-to-float conversion) manually.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are asking for too much. You'll have to define `price=` exactly as it is in your commented-out code.

`attr_accessor` is just a simplified way to define

```
def price=(val)
  @price = val
end
```

(with no type-conversion) plus the getter method.

Obviously when you define `price=`, the `attr_accessor :price` is not needed anymore (only `attr_reader`).

Finally, I'd rather write `val.to_f` instead of `Float(val)`.

Comment: `attr_accessor` is *not* syntactic sugar, it's just a boring regular old message send.

Answer (score 0):

Based on tomgi answer, here is a version that supports multiple attributes so you can use

```
casting_attr_accessor :price, :amount, Float
```

Put somewhere in load path, in Rails I use initializers

```
# config/initializers/casting_attr_accessor.rb
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940255/287166
class Class
  def casting_attr_accessor(*accessors, type)
    Array(accessors).each do |accessor|
      define_method(accessor) do
        instance_variable_get("@#{accessor}")
      end

      define_method("#{accessor}=") do |val|
        instance_variable_set("@#{accessor}", Kernel.send(type.to_s, val)) unless val.nil?
      end
    end
  end
end
```