# multiparameter error with datetime_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following code in my form.

```
<%= f.datetime_select(:date_time, :prompt => {:day => 'Day', :month => 'Month', :year => 'Year'}, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year + 2, :minute_step => 15, :include_blank => false) %> if either one is blank.
```

When one of the fields is left blank, **I get:**

```
1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes
```

The params that are being passed are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"kQpfsj5RxnDtxkvBdwPEFnX1fY6euKnMQeDRAkvJvIE=",
 "event"=>{"description"=>"",
 "venue"=>"",
 "street"=>"",
 "city"=>"",
 "country_id"=>"",
 "date_time(1i)"=>"",
 "date_time(2i)"=>"",
 "date_time(3i)"=>"",
 "date_time(4i)"=>"00",
 "date_time(5i)"=>"00",
 "ticket_url"=>""},
 "x"=>"94",
 "y"=>"12"}
```

Anyone know why this is occurring?

There seems to be a "dirty" fix for this at this [link](http://osdir.com/ml/RubyonRailsTalk/2009-06/msg00274.html), but perhaps there is a better solution in Rails 3?

Comment: Is your date_time field virtual (no actual db column)? If so gabeodess's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Christian.  This is a bug in Rails that checks the database to infer the type needed for the multiparameter attributes.  My guess is that your "date_time" attribute is not associated with a time column in your database.

I recently tackled this problem where I wanted a non-database attribute to accepted multiparameter attributes, this was the best solution I could come up with:

I found myself wanting to set an `attr_accessor` to handle passing a date to my model in a `form_for` tag with the `f.datetime_select` helper. So this is what I had:

Model:

```
attr_accessor :my_time
```

View:

```
<%= f.datetime_select :my_time %>
```

Unfortunately when I submit my form I get this:

```
1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes
```

Well it turns out that this is actually a Rails bug a ticket for which has been submitted. In the meantime how do we make this work? The only solution I could find that was remotely attractive was to make use of `composed_of` as a replacement for `attr_accessor`. so...

Model:

```
  composed_of :my_time,
              :class_name => 'Time',
              :mapping => %w(Time to_s),
              :constructor => Proc.new{ |item| item },
              :converter => Proc.new{ |item| item }
```

I know almost nothing about the `composed_of` method so you should probably do your own reading on it, but what I do know is that it creates both a reader and writer for the given instance variable, and more importantly, the setter accepts multiparameter attributes. How I chose the options:

class_name: the name of our expected class. In this case, `Time`
mapping: the first argument is the class and the second argument seems to work with any method that an instance of the class responds to. I chose `to_s` 
constructor: Not really sure how this is supposed to work. Seems to be called when `@my_time` is `nil`.
converter: Not really sure how this is supposed to work. Seems to be called when from my_time=, but doesn't seem to be applied with mass assignment.
One problem I ran into with this solution was that times were getting set in UTC instead of the environment's time zone. So unfortunately we cannot use my_time directly, but instead need to convert it to the proper time zone:

```
Time.zone.parse(my_time.to_s(:number))
```

Comment: Yippie! You just saved me a whole day :) Nice hack

Comment: This still appears to be a problem, @gabeodess. Do you happen to know the ticket number in Rails for this issue?

Comment: The original solution from the link is here: http://web.archive.org/web/20120121005808/http://gabeodess.heroku.com/posts/14

Answer (score 1):

[What Does ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors Mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93277/what-does-activerecordmultiparameterassignmenterrors-mean)

```
def initialize(attributes={})
  date_hack(attributes, "deliver_date")
  super(attributes)
end   

def date_hack(attributes, property)
  keys, values = [], []
  attributes.each_key {|k| keys << k if k =~ /#{property}/ }.sort
  keys.each { |k| values << attributes[k]; attributes.delete(k); }
  attributes[property] = values.join("-")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using a date dropdown that wasn't backed by a database attribute. I wrote a little Rack middleware to cope with the problem:

```
class DateParamsParser
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if %w{POST PUT}.include? env['REQUEST_METHOD']
      params = Rack::Utils.parse_query(env["rack.input"].read, "&")

      # selects only relevant params like 'date1(1i)'
      filtered_params = params.select{ |key, value| key =~ /\(\di\)/ }
      # delete date params
      filtered_params.each { |key, value| params.delete(key) }

      # returns something like {'date1' => [2012, 5, 14], 'date2' => [2002, 3, 28]}
      date_array_params = filtered_params.sort.reduce({}) do |array_params, keyvalue|
        date_key = keyvalue.first.match(/(.+)\(/)[1] + ']'
        array_params[date_key] ||= []
        array_params[date_key] << keyvalue.last
        array_params
      end

      # Creates params with date strings like {'date1' => '2012-5-14', 'date2' => '2002-3-28'}
      date_params = Hash[date_array_params.map{ |key, date_array| [key, date_array.join('-')] }]

      params.merge! date_params
      env["rack.input"] = StringIO.new(Rack::Utils.build_query(params))
      env["rack.input"].rewind
    end

    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

And in application.rb I put

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, "DateParamsParser"
```

Note that I only build a date string here. So if you also require time you'll need to build the `date_params` differently.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with the model below

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :sid, :check_in, :credit_card_number, :expiration_date
    attr_accessible :expiration_date
end
```

The corresponding form with the field for the expiration date:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :expiration_date %>
  <%= f.date_select(:expiration_date, start_year: Time.now.year + 3, :end_year => Time.now.year - 3, discard_day: true) %>
</div>
```

as mentioned by @gabeodess the problem is checking the database to infer the type accordingly the solution I did for it was adding the following code to the model to put the type of the needed attribute in this case :expiration_date so the model is modified to be the following

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :sid, :check_in, :credit_card_number, :expiration_date
  attr_accessible :expiration_date
  columns_hash["expiration_date"] = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new("expiration_date", nil, "date")
end
```

Hope this is useful

Comment: ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new works but kills the ability to do db:schema:load for me

Answer (score -1):

Remove `:include_blank => false` from your code.

```
<%= f.datetime_select(:date_time, :prompt => {:day => 'Day', :month => 'Month', :year => 'Year'}, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year + 2, :minute_step => 15 %>
```

Thanks....

Comment: Still getting the same error. I now have: <%= f.datetime_select(:date_time, :prompt => {:day => 'Day', :month => 'Month', :year => 'Year'}, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => Date.today.year + 2, :minute_step => 15) %>

Answer (score -5):

I was facing the same problem.
I just added **attr_accessible** for that attribute and it works fine.

Hope it helps.