# How to define virtual attribute for date_select drop menu using active model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I am using active model for payment process in my application , but i am not able to add field for credit card expiration date, since it throws error as below
**undefined method `card_expiration_date(3i)='**.

In my model:

```
class CartServer

  include ActiveModel::Validation

  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :card_expiration_date
```

In view:

```
f.date_select(
  :card_expiration_date,
  :add_month_numbers => false,
  :discard_day => true,
  :start_year => (Date.today.year-10),
  :end_year => (Date.today.year+10),
  :order=>[ :month,:year]
)
```

Comment: Your code looks incomplete. Please updated.

Comment: code looks ok ..what is the problem?

Comment: I'm having the same problem in case you've found a solution.

Comment: @MattHuggins, I placed the below code in my model.





columns_hash["card_expiration_date"] = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new("card_expiration_date", nil, "time")

Where "card_expiration_date" is my attribute name

Comment: Thanks!  For reference, there is an open issue/pull request on the Rails repo to get this fixed: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8189

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will work in Rails 6:

```rb
class CartServer
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  include ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment

  attribute :card_expiration_date, :date
end
```

There are two things here that are important:

- Declaring the `attribute` with type `:date`. In an ActiveRecord model this type information comes from the database schema, but since we're using ActiveModel we need to explicitly declare it.
- Including `ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment` to get support for multi-part parameter assignment. The params from the form will look something like this:

  ```
  {
    "card_expiration_date(1i)" => "2020",
    "card_expiration_date(2i)" => "12",
    "card_expiration_date(3i)" => "31",
  }
  ```

  The `ActiveModel::AttributeAssignment` module we get from `ActiveModel::Model` doesn't know how to convert this into a date, so we need to pull in the more fully featured `ActiveRecord` version instead.

Answer (score -2):

How to set an attr_accessor date via Rails date_select and have Rails handle the multi-attributes automatically: https://gist.github.com/paulsturgess/5500858

Answer (score -2):

attribute :card_expiration_date, Type::Date.new